# Change the bullet of each \item

Tags: beamer, itemize

Sorry, may be the title is not clear. In fact, I need to make a list of advantages and disadvantages and I want to note the advantages as + and disadvantages as -. How can I change the full circle of item to + or - sign?

```
 \documentclass[compress,red]{beamer}
 \usepackage{etex}
 \mode<presentation>
 \usetheme{Warsaw}
   \usepackage[applemac]{inputenc}%les accents pour mac
   \usepackage{subfigure}
  \usepackage{amsmath}
  \usepackage{epsfig} 
     \usepackage{graphicx}
   \usepackage[all,knot]{xy}
    \xyoption{arc}
   \usepackage{setspace}
     \begin{document}
      \section{section1 }
     \frame[shrink]{\frametitle{Titre de la fenetre}
     \begin{itemize}

         \item point1
        \item point2
       \item point3
        \item point4
        \item point5
       \end{itemize}

        }
```

Comment: `\item[+]` is what you want?

Comment: @Sigur, thanks, yes I resolve it. sorry, if the question is evident. I can delete it.

Comment: You can test other variants, using math symbols as optional argument. For example, `\item[$-$]` is different from `\item[-]` and from `\item[--]`.

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Just an addition to @Sigur's answer. You can define macros, say `\pro` and `\con`,

```
\newcommand\pro{\item[$+$]}
\newcommand\con{\item[$-$]}
```

to save some repetitive typing, and make the source code more readable.

### MWE

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Warsaw}
\begin{document}

\newcommand\pro{\item[$+$]}
\newcommand\con{\item[$-$]}

\frame{
    \begin{itemize}
        \pro advantage
        \con disadvantage
        \item neutral
    \end{itemize}
}

\end{document}
```

### Output

[image]

Comment: How can I do `>` ?

Comment: @alper: Try `\item[\texttt{>}]`

Comment: can I also try: `label=\scriptsize$\blacktriangleright$`?

Answer (score 11):

As Sigur commented, you can use the optional argument to `\item` to specify the bullet:

```
\item[+] Some positive point
\item[$-$] Some negative point %use $-$ instead of - for a real minus sign.
\item Some neutral point
```

[image]

In my opinion the minus sign isn't great for this (not very clear), but you can use almost anything for your bullet, including colour commands (e.g. `\item[\textcolor{red}{-}]`).  The [comprehensive LaTeX symbols list](http://www.tex.ac.uk/tex-archive/info/symbols/comprehensive/symbols-a4.pdf) may help you to find something good, such as `\oplus` and `\ominus` (circled versions, normally used as binary operators) from the `mathabx` package.

EDIT: code updated thanks to comment from Przemysław Scherwentke, but I can't easily updated the image from here.

Comment: Only not `\item[-]` but `\item[$-$]` if it should be a minus sign.

Comment: @PrzemysławScherwentke, I've updated the code, will do the image tomorrow if I remember.

Answer (score 2):

You can use

```
\usepackage{paralist}
```

with

```
\begin{compactitem}[-]
\item
\end{compactitem}
```

and any optional argument at [] to to specify the bullet.

`\begin{enumerate}[(i)][8]` or
`\begin{compactitem}[$\circ$]` or

have a look at paralist

Additional pro: save space with compactitem